# How to create jquery obj dynamiquely whith multiple values by key?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create one object filtered by data attribute

```js
var pop_cp = $('.pop-cp'),
  pop_cp_obj = {};

$.each(pop_cp, function(index, value) {
  var id_race = $(value).data('id_html');
  var el = $(this).filter(`[data-id_html='${id_race}']`);
  pop_cp_obj[id_race] = [el];
});

console.log(pop_cp_obj);
```

Résult

```
{
  race_vg: Array(1), 
  race_tjv: Array(1)
}
```

For example, i willing be have more elements in array at 'race_vg' key, however i get only the last iteration.
Your help will be gold =)
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `$.each()` loop you need to check if `pop_cp_obj[id_race]` has already been defined. If it has, you need to `push()` the new item in to it, not overwrite it:

```
$.each(pop_cp, function(index, value) {
  var id_race = $(value).data('id_html');
  var el = $(this).filter(`[data-id_html='${id_race}']`);

  if (pop_cp_obj[id_race]) {
    pop_cp_obj[id_race].push(el);
  } else {
    pop_cp_obj[id_race] = [el];
  }
});
```